# python 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_frame'

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python. Just following some sample code 
this is the error I get:

> 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_frame'

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels
import statsmodels.api as sm
from datetime import datetime


tech_list =['4938.TW','2317.TW']
tickers=['4938.TW','2317.TW']
end= '2014-12-31'
start= '2014-01-01'
print(start)
print (end)

from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import fix_yahoo_finance as yf
yf.pdr_override(tickers)
data=pdr.get_data_yahoo(tech_list,start,end) 
data.to_frame().head(10)
```

I want to get this

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuQ2u.jpg)

Comment: I think you are trying to covert the dataframe. Try `data.head(10)` and let me know the result.

Comment: ok i  know why error. because data is dataframe so can't to frame? i try code data.head(10) but the form not same . how can i merge Symbols to same ?

Comment: Already Answered here: [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49566862/dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-to-frame/49566995)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your 'data' variable is already a dataframe.
Check with print(type(data))

since it's already a dataframe you can use

print(data.head(10))

to get your result